# Alert user to session being replaced by concurrent login

Tags: java, session, spring-security

We have a spring security application with a pretty standard setup. Currently we only allow 1 session per principal, rejecting additional logins by the same principal until the first session is logged out or expired (maximumSessions=1, excpeptionIfMaximumExceeded=true).

I'd like to change this so that when a principal logs in a second time with a currently active login on another session the first session is invalidated/replaced. This is easily accomplished using the provided spring security concurrent session control strategy but I am having trouble figuring out how to alert the user. When a user's session is replaced the session is invalidated by the logout handler. The next request will get a redirect to the login page with a error code on the query string. However, if the request which gets this redirect is an image or other non-programatic call I'm unable to handle this.

It seems like I need to put the user into an inbetween state, where they have a session but it is expired and they need to log back in if they didn't mean to replace their original session. However I don't see a good way to do this.

Is there an example of a setup like this somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought of working out a polling mechanism in javascript to alert the user when their session is about to be invalidated? This way they will know that their session isnt valid and possibly have a chance to refresh it in case they have partially filled out forms or text areas.

This can also work from the login side. You can add a step after login if they have another session active and have them verify they want to invalidate it.

It seems that an in between step isnt necessary because, generally,authentication should be boolean.  Either they are authenticated or they arent. The inbetween zone might be tougher to handle all cases for.

Comment: We currently have a polling mechanism for session expired due to timeout that we would adapt to this. We could handle it by having another step at login but I'm more interested in cleanly handling the evicted session on the UI side.I agree that security really should be boolean but I don't want a session to "magically" go back to the login screen if the last request on the invalid session is caught by a request we can't handle the return status of, i.e. an image or script include.